# Google Cloud Repositories does not show images in markdown file

Tags: repository, bitbucket, r-markdown, markdown

It is almost 3 days that I am working on finding a solution to display the images in my Google cloud repository.
I did the same on bitbucket account and it works fine, but when I push everything into the google cloud repository the image does not show up in my README.md file.
I do not have any nested folder and all the files are placed into the root.
bellow you can find the syntax I used in my markdown file:

```
![google](google.png "Optional title")
![google](/google.png "Optional title")
![google](/master:google.png "Optional title")
```

None of them are working, I found another post on stack overflow that Google cloud repositories are a kind of bare repository. does it means there NO way to do that?

Could you please help me out with this?

Comment: Good question! Does it work without the optional title?

Comment: I tested it once and did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible. Such a feature is not listed in the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs). Too bad are not a lot of people complaining about this. The only thing I could find was the [following](https://www.slant.co/versus/530/21847/~bitbucket_vs_google-cloud-source-repositories):

[image]

The only option is mirroring to Github or Bitbucket, but I think that is not what something you want. You could also just use Github instead of Cloud Repositories, which now integrates nicely with the google cloud platform, specifically Cloud Build.